# Pulling the ID's of four different rows in sqlite3 randomly?

Tags: random, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm in need of some assistance with Ruby on Rails and Sqlite3 again.

This is what I did four times:

```
<%= Bullet.select(:content).order('random()').limit(1).collect { |b| b.content } %>
```

But instead of four different random "bullets" it will do four of the same bullets chosen randomly from the list of bullets I have.

I also have tried `select * from bullets order by random() limit 4;` in sqlite3 (using the program sqliteman) and have also done `select * from bullets order by random() limit 1;` four times.

Any idea on how I can do this successfully in Ruby on Rails by accessing the database table and using embedded ruby (.erb)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer in case anyone ever looks across this:
Posted by MurifoX (so all credit goes to him/her)

```
<% random_bullets = Bullet.all %>
<ul>
  <% 4.times do %>
    <li><%= random_bullets.sample.content %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: But doesn't this query ALL random_bullets from the database while only using four?